# What does the round icon inside Xcode's filter fields mean?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

[image: Round icon near the search field]

Maybe I'm just me that don't grasp the meaning of a simple thing, but I really can not understand the meaning of the round icon that is next to the search field of the panel objects of Interface Builder of Xcode. Someone would know help me?

Comment: Although I cannot find a direct reference to the icon in the Xcode docs, I would bet that it is simply an indicator that a filter is applied (the same icon exist on the navigator pane at the bottom) and letting the user know that only a subset (hence the semi-filled circle...) of elements is visible in the respective list

Comment: And just found some old docs regarding the icon [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-structure_navigator/articles/About_the_Project_Navigator.html)

Comment: Alladinian, you should put that as the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**That is the filter icon for Xcode, used to filter a list that is already showing.**

In each filter field that's available you don't have to enter the beginning of the name to get a match. The most powerful of all the filters is the Quick Find feature (shown at the bottom), which doesn't even require the characters to be adjacent, for a match to be successful.

Did you know that you can also filter method names that appear at the top of your Editor?

1. Tap on the popup button:
   [image]
2. Start typing to filter the list. As you can see, the entered characters don't have to be adjacent to produce matched results:
   [image]

Contrast that to the search icon, visible at the top of the Find navigator panel:
[image]

There is also a filter field at the bottom of the Find navigator, to enable filtering through search results. I think it is supposed to resemble a half-filled magnifying glass, but it is missing the handle:
[image]

A filter field is also at the bottom of the Project navigator:
[image]

And, let's not forget about the filter field at the bottom of each of the library panels (Template library, Code Snippet library, Object library, and Media library). That really comes in handy, especially with all the UI components available on Mac OS:
[image]

But if you have a lot of files in your project, then I recommend using Quick Find (Shft-Cmd-O). You can type any letters for what you're looking for, and it digs up results of several types of objects, including file names and method names. It performs a powerful regex-style search that doesn't require the entered characters to be adjacent in the matched results. Notice that there is no filter icon here, because a list is not displayed before you begin filtering:
[image]